# Vacuum cleaner charging works only with the original adapter - why?

Tags: charging, adapter, nimh

I have this old robotic vacuum cleaner that I got cheap and was using for a while: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvj8BmijDn4 (not my video)

Now however the charging adapter broke and I've been trying to replace it which seems like a straightforward task, but apparently I'm not educated enough to make it work. First off, some facts:

- The old adapter is a simple AC-DC adapter designated JDA-22, outputting DC 22V 450 mA.
- The battery of the vacuum cleaner is a 14.4V 3500mAh Ni-MH battery pack (something like [this](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32906998724.html?spm=a2g0o.productlist.0.0.314b377dP3f1fU&algo_pvid=81ba8014-f15c-422e-a553-307805004cc9&algo_expid=81ba8014-f15c-422e-a553-307805004cc9-1&btsid=ee9b2188-a846-4c61-91d4-b88805070428&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_7,searchweb201603_53))
- Between the adapter and the battery is the charging dock with some basic electronics and a relay that probably does some regulation and magic for charging.

[image]

My theory was that I could just order a replacement adapter so I got myself a new 22V 1A DC adapter that fits nicely. Whenever I plug it into the charging dock, the LEDs turn on and everything seems fine, but when I connect the vacuum cleaner to the dock, it charges for less than a second and then I can hear the relay click inside the charging dock and it turns off for a moment (LEDs go off, charging stops). It then comes back up again and continues in this click off, turn on, click off, turn on loop until I disconnect the vacuum cleaner from the dock. Seems weird enough.

So I measured the voltage from the old charging adapter (it's more physically broken than electronically so it's still barely usable) and it's outputting 24.x volts instead of the specified 22. I have a look inside the charging dock and the relay has a designation RWH-SH-124D. The specification tells me that the "Rated coil voltage" and the "DC contacts rating" (whatever they are... not sure. Specified working voltage I think?) are both 24 volts and the new charger is giving them 22 volts instead of 24, so maybe that's not enough to power the relay. I don't have any idea if the broken old charger is the original or someone just retrofitted it because it worked.

Alright, let's get a new 24V adapter. Done (24V 1A DC). Plug it in and get exactly the same behavior as with the 22V adapter. At this point I'm at my wits' end and come here asking for guidance on how to proceed.

What I think may be happening (and have no idea how to fix):

- The battery is drawing as much current as possible and the old adapter was only giving it 450 mA which was safe, but now that the new adapters can provide 1A, there's a safety feature in the charging dock to turn off charging if too much current is withdrawn.
- The charging dock itself is confused by too much current and just fails under these conditions.
- There's some kind of a third parameter in this process besides voltage and current that I'm not aware of or can't think of that is different between the old and new adapters.

Will you help me make this old boy clean some more? :)

## EDIT:

So what's wrong with the old one? First of all, the contacts have come loose so they can be pressed into the housing of the adapter so you can't really plug it in any more (EU type). Secondly there's a weird patch on the side of the plastic housing that looks a bit like it has melted at some point and it used to get rather hot while charging so I don't feel overly comfortable using it even though it technically works. The old adapter is similar to [this](https://www.poweradapter.co/jda22u-ac-adapter-22vdc-500ma-power-glide-charger-power-supply-p-666.html) I think, but not exactly, because mine is an EU type plug and mine is rated at 450 mA not 500. Here are some pics of the old adapter to give an idea of what's wrong:
[image]
[image]

I can't open it up at the moment because it screws together with some special screws and I don't have that driver at hand.

## EDIT 2:

Here's a picture of all the adapters with the left one being the old adapter.
[image]

Comment: The robot vacuum cleaner might be putting the whole 22v of the adapter over the batery, and it just uses the current limit in the adapter so limit the charging

Comment: What is the current rating of the old charger? I'm guessing more than 1 amp?

Comment: _"the charging adapter broke" - exactly how is it broken? Can you take it apart and see what is in it?  Is this it? https://www.poweradapter.co/jda22u-ac-adapter-22vdc-500ma-power-glide-charger-power-supply-p-666.html

Comment: @RonBeyer question says 450 mA

Comment: I missed that, thanks.

Comment: @BruceAbbott Updated the question with details about the old one

Comment: _"there's a weird patch on the side of the plastic housing that looks a bit like it has melted at some point and it used to get rather hot while charging"_ it might have a resistor to limit charging current, and the DC might not be smoothed so the peak voltage is much higher than 24V (meter reads average voltage). You should take it apart by whatever means necessary, eg. drill out the screws or hacksaw through the case, then trace the internal circuit.

Comment: @wanaryytel is that really an AC/DC adaptor? For 240 mA, it does seem rather large.

Comment: @MarcusMüller It could contain a mains-level transformer. At ~10W (it's 450mA, not 240) it looks like roughly the appropriate size for that.

Comment: @MarcusMüller Added a picture of all the adapter labels, maybe I don't know what to look for. The old adapter is about twice the size of the new ones, but I thought it's because the old adapter is **old** [tech] and the new ones are **new** [tech]. Maybe there's more to that?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Thanks, will take it into account, will try to work finding tools to open it up.

Comment: @wanaryytel ah, the security transformer symbol on the old device might indicate there's actually an old-school transformer going on inside that device! If wound with copper thin enough on a flux-limited core, that can be quite an effective current limiter. Try your new supply with maybe 10Ω or 5Ω resistance in series, maybe the charger depends on the voltage benignly dropping as soon as it starts to draw serious current, and your new supplies are simply "too good".